# Performance drop in Python loop with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2

I'm using Python 3.6,  my table1 is containing a rather large amount of data of which I just need merely 10% contained in the area (of the table "area"). I figured creating a view first and parse through it instead of the full table1 could widely improve the performances, but instead I see that around the 200th iteration the speed dramatically fall down to something like one iteration per second (while at first it was a continuous flow of numbers streaming on the screen). Here is the code :

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=db_name user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("create view temp as select st_setsrid(the_geom::geometry,2154), table1.gid from tout.area, public.table1 where (st_contains(area.geom,st_setsrid(table1.the_geom::geometry,2154)));")
cur.execute("select count(*) from temp")
nbtotal = cur.fetchone()[0]
print(nbtotal)
for i in range(nbtotal):
    print(i+1, " sur ", nbtotal)
    cur.execute ("insert into tout.table2 (geom) select st_setsrid FROM temp order by gid limit 1 offset "+str(i)+ ";")
    conn.commit()
cur.execute("drop view temp;")
conn.commit()
```

Any idea on why this is happening and how to solve it ? Before that I tried to not create a view (and so make a pre-selection), and the loop slowed down after few thousands iteration (which I understand is quite normal), but far from that rythm. A workaround would be to load all the datas and then filter the result and write it in a new table. But it doesn't look like a proper long-term solution.

Thanks

Comment: might be too many inserts and separate commits - transactions in short period of time, have you checked what happens on server side, is there any auto-vacuum , auto-analyze kicking in. how many indexes you have on  table, are there any triggers on that table which might strain database performance, have you checked PostgreSQL logs are there checkpoint related warnings etc?

Comment: This looks like your data is taking a round-trip from the db through your app code and back unnecessarily. And even then you're doing single sql's job insert by insert. Performance is going to be miserable, comparatibely.

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy I'm afraid I am quite a newbie in databases, so these are operation I didn't even know existed. I don't understand how it could be to many inserts. When I launched it without the preselection it didn't have any performance problem, even though it parsed through 10 times longer table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to do it all at once?:

```
cur.execute ('''
    insert into tout.table2 (geom)
    select st_setsrid(the_geom::geometry, 2154)
    from
        tout.area
        inner join
        public.table1 on
            st_contains(area.geom, st_setsrid(table1.the_geom::geometry, 2154))
''')
```

Comment: This would most likely work, but it would still parse through the totality of the table1, which I'd specially like to avoid for big datasets (this is the purpose of my question).

Comment: @GuiOmClair you should try it, especially if you're not very experienced with RDBMSes as you say. Measure rather than assume performance.

Comment: @pvg Wow indeed ! My bad for my previous comment... It works like a charm !

Answer (score -1):

In fact it seems the problem came from the way the view is existing in PostgreSQL. Creating a materialized view seems to have solved my problem. If anyone has an explanation it would be welcome though.

In case it could be of some help to anyone, here is the new version of my code :

```
import os, psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=db_name user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("create materialized view temp as select st_setsrid(the_geom::geometry,2154), table1.gid from tout.area, public.table1 where (st_contains(area.geom,st_setsrid(table1.the_geom::geometry,2154))); select count(*) from temp")
nbtotal = cur.fetchone()[0]
print(nbtotal)
for i in range(nbtotal):
    print(i+1, " sur ", nbtotal)
    cur.execute ("insert into tout.table2 (geom) select st_setsrid FROM temp order by gid limit 1 offset "+str(i)+ ";")
cur.execute("drop materialized view temp;")
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Using string concatenation to form SQL commands (instead of parameterized bind variables) is prone to what are called "injection attacks". Even if your values are integers, this should be avoided -- answers on StackOverflow are a teaching resource, and we don't want to teach bad practices.

Comment: As a bigger-picture item -- materialized views are appropriate when they're going to be reused; not for transient purposes. If you want to limit content considered in an expensive query, that's what WHERE clauses are for -- the database's optimizer will try to perform cheap filters before expensive ones.